# Restore edge/epub association AND behavior AND icon

Tags: windows-10, pdf, file-association, microsoft-edge

I could not have epub files open by edge back. I tried to associate the program `%windir%\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe` but edge just would not lauch (nothing happens).

I restored the recommended files association, and had pdf and html files open by edge. I saw that in the registry there is this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.pdf\OpenWithProgids]
"FirefoxHTML"=""
"AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723"=hex(0):
```

I created a custom key for epub files:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.epub\OpenWithProgids]
"FirefoxHTML"=""
"AppXd4nrz8ff68srnhf9t5a8sbjyar1cr723"=hex(0):
```

But in that case, I get a pdf icon for the epub files, and edge does open but it will only download the epub, it won't open the content the way it does it with pdf files.

How can I restore 1) the proper epub association, 2) edge behavior and 2) file icon ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Microsoft [declared EDGE will no longer be able to show EPUB files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517840/microsoft-edge-download-an-epub-app-to-keep-reading), so when they get the [KB4522355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4522355/windows-10-update-kb4522355) patch into your system to kill that ability, it's gone forever. As Microsoft stated, other EPUB reader apps are available, including the Open Source [fbReader](https://fbreader.org/win32), as well as 12 others in the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Sorry but I was opening them few minutes ago.

Comment: Were you online? Connected to the Internet? Microsoft killed your ability in Edge to do that over the wire.

Comment: I had indeed KB4519573 and KB4522355 installed in between. It may be one of them. Which one killed this ability ?

Comment: the second one: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4522355/windows-10-update-kb4522355  I saw new many bugs and freezes also.

Comment: After removing KB4522355, the behavior was restored, but not the icon.

Answer (score 0):

The patch [KB4522355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4522355/windows-10-update-kb4522355) which removes the ability to open epub files with edge can be avoided or removed; in that case, the registry keys in the OP will work.